# R - How to fetch data from multiple pages of a table in an URL that remains static?

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on R language and I am suppose to fetch table data from an URL which is static. The URL has .aspx extension.

When I log in into the site, which is password protected I have a table on the first page. But the table has multiple pages like 1,2, and so on. I am able to fetch the data from the first page of the table, but when I click on next page there is no change in URL.

I want to get data from all the pages of this table and write it to a csv but I am unable to fetch data from the second page onward. I did inspect element for the site but not able to find what is the exact change in the html that I need to fetch. I am using **RSelenium** for this web scraping.

Below is the code that I have written so far and able to fetch the data from the first page of the table.

```
library(devtools)
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(plyr)

######################

RSelenium::checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver() 
startServer()
remDr$open()
site <- paste0(url) 
remDr$navigate(site)
elem <- remDr$findElement(using="id",value="ctl00_ContentBody_rgridPDPList_ctl00")
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
b <- read_html(elemtxt)
data <- b %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%.[[1]] %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
finaldata <- data[c(-1,-2,-3),c(-1,-16,-17,-18)]### Removes the unnecessary columns and rows.
```

I tried using `readHTMLTable(url)` but it didn't work for me, may be because the site is password protected. Using RSelenium, the sites first opens in Firefox browser and then I provide the username password as of now and navigate to the page where the table is present and then I run the above code.

I shall be highly obliged if you help me regarding the same. Also let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: can you share the URL?

Comment: Hello @epo3
I am sorry I can't share the actual site as it is my company website and I am not allowed to share the link. But I came across a site which is same as per my requirement.
The URL is [link](http://sheriff.franklincountyohio.gov/search/real-estate/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d12%2f26%2f2014%26foreclosureType%3d%26sortType%3ddefendant)
But this site has a button Print Sale List, which is not the case for me. I need to click on next page button to see the second page data.

Comment: The URL is http://sheriff.franklincountyohio.gov/search/real-estate/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d12%2f26%2f2014%26foreclosureType%3d%26sortType%3ddefendant. But this site has a button Print Sale List which on clicking gives me the entire details on one page.
I dont want any button to be clicked just scrap data from all the pages of the table one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This was achieved using clickElement on the next page button on the site.
Thanks.